# about dbo schema

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I created a login ABCLOGIN, and a user ABCUSER, under ABCLOGIN for a database ABC_db

I then connected to ABC_db using ABCLOGIN & executed the following query :

```
execute as user='dbo'
```

It gives the following error:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo"
>   does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use `execute as user='ABCUSER'`? There is no user named 'dbo' in your description.

**EDIT:**

Hmm ok, but you didn't grant any permissions to the user 'dbo'. If there is a default user 'dbo' you must execute this: `GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::ABCUSER to dbo` Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173848.aspx) for further details.

Comment: sir, there's a user dbo by default, when i see in object explorer in sql server, under the Databases-->ABC_db-->Security-->Users-->dbo, guest, sys, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, ABCUSER. I found these 5 entries 4 default & one which i created myself : ABCUSER